# Optimize the SQL query for Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have to generate a simple Up time report for gates on railway stations. if there is any error for any gate, it is in the DB with specific reason and startTime and EndTime of outage. have few scenarios needs to take care of:

1. If there are 2 gates on one station, one is working for first 15 days of month and second is working or up for next 15 Days, so overall one of both gates are working. So value for this station should be 100%. If both gates and down for any number of days, that will not come in this percentage.

I have write down a query but it is taking 5-6 minutes to execute for few hundreds of thousands of records.So at that it will choke the system.

```
declare @dt_start datetime, @dt_end datetime
set @dt_start = '2019-04-01 00:00';
set @dt_end = '2019-04-30 23:59';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #minutesTime;
with cte_Dates as (
        SELECT @dt_start as uptimeMinute
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,1,uptimeMinute)
        FROM cte_Dates
        WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,1,uptimeMinute) < @dt_end
    )

SELECT * 
INTO #minutesTime FROM cte_Dates
WHERE CAST(uptimeMinute as time) >= '05:00:00'
or CAST(uptimeMinute as time) < '02:00:00'
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT
uptimeMinute,
count(DISTINCT o.ReaderID) as numOfflineReaders
FROM #minutesTime m
CROSS JOIN Readers r 
JOIN Outages o
ON r.ReaderId = o.ReaderId
WHERE 
uptimeMinute BETWEEN o.OutageStart AND o.OutageEnd
GROUP BY 
uptimeMinute having count(DISTINCT o.ReaderID)=3
ORDER BY 
uptimeMinute;
```

Table Definitions are:

Readers:

```
ReaderId NotificationsDisabled
1        0
2        1
```

Outages:

```
OutageId    SourceType  SourceId    OutageStart                     OutageEnd                       OutageSeconds   ReaderId
1           Faults          1       2019-03-28 10:13:35.6700000     2019-03-31 00:21:45.5900000     223690          24
```

[image: Execution Plan for last query]

Comment: would you also include the execution plan of your query

Comment: @ARr0w, please check the question

Comment: @RamSingh . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question.  Focus on the  data in the two or three tables you are referencing.  Show the results you want -- all as text tables.  Explain the logic clearly and set up a db<> fiddle.  Then explain that you have a query that seems to take a long time.  I can read your initial paragraph, but I have no idea how the explanation relates to your data, so I'm not going to read beyond the first paragraph.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Rather than breaking a month in minutes and hunting around it would be more efficient to find all of the outage rows that overlap the month and process them to determine to total downtime in the month and any overlapping downtime. It isn't clear from your tables how to tell which readers are assigned to a given station. The general check for overlapping ranges is `Start1 <= End2 and Start2 <= End1`. Refer to the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag wiki for an explanation.

Comment: You are showing two queries. Which ones is the slow one?

Comment: @TheImpaler, last Select is taking time, where having join on readers and Outages tables..

Answer (score 0):

Your Date builder (using recursion) is probably a bit inefficient.
You could try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2019-04-01 00:00'  , @EndDate DATETIME= '2019-04-30 23:59';



WITH dates as (
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, nbr - 1, @StartDate) as uptimeMinute
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id , c.a ) AS Nbr
          FROM      
          (SELECT c.object_id, 1 as a FROM sys.columns c
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT c.object_id, 0 as a FROM sys.columns c) c
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
)
SELECT uptimeMinute into #minute
from dates
WHERE CAST(uptimeMinute as time) >= '05:00:00'
or CAST(uptimeMinute as time) < '02:00:00'
```